# Toggle window scroll bar

Tags: window, scroll-bars

It's not clear to me how to *disable* a window scroll bar.

I have frame scrollbars turned off:

```
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
```

I can enable a window scroll bar with

```
(set-window-scroll-bars (selected-window) nil 'right)
```

I expect the following to remove the scroll bar, but it doesn't.  It only removes the fringe adjacent to the scroll bar.

```
(set-window-scroll-bars (selected-window) nil nil nil nil)
```

Checking `(window-current-scroll-bars (selected-window))`, it returns `nil` as expected.  My understanding is that `window-current-scroll-bars` should tell me the dimensions of the window's scroll bar, returning `nil` if there is no scroll bar.

Maybe it's a frame scroll bar that somehow snuck in?  Yet `(frame-current-scroll-bars)` returns `nil` as expected.

If I do something like `C-h f` or `M-x` after calling `(set-window-scroll-bars (selected-window) nil nil nil nil)`, the scroll bar will disappear.  Yet simply switching windows does nothing.  The scroll bar remains.

I'm confused!  Am I missing something?

I am using `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2018-05-30`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `(set-window-scroll-bars (selected-window) nil nil nil nil)` removes the scroll bar as expected, starting from `emacs -Q`, on Emacs 27.0.50

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be [a bug in Emacs](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=33694#8).  Although the [bug fix has been pushed to the Emacs-26 branch](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=emacs-26&id=24b5026fb6b622966fd773178608617fa2f8add2), these changes either don't solve the problem or are not reflected in the latest Emacs 26 build, which is the version I am using (i.e. `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2018-05-30`).

Trying the [latest Emacs-27 development snapshot](https://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/windows/emacs-27/), the problem has been fixed, as indicated by @Tyler.

Comment: That fix will be available once emacs-26.2 is released.

Comment: You can accept this answer.  See [if something described in the question turned out to be a bug and was fixed later](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/622/39388).